# Applying css to specific <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I apply css to a specific  tag, but it's not working. The following is my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="fixedwidth">
            <p><span class="date">2 April 2014 Last update at 15:23</p>
            <h1>Norwich 'explosion': Two people dead</h1>
            <img class="headlineimg" src="pictures/headline.jpg" />
            <div class="newsitem">
                <p>Two people have died in a suspected explosion at an industrial estate in Norwich.</p>
                <p><a href="">Protest shuts Heathrow Airport runway</a></p>
                <p><a href="">Harman 'happy to be overruled' on cuts</a></p>
                <p><a href="">Get poor pupils 'into schools early'</a></p>
                <p><a href="">Bird flu confirmed at Lancashire farm</a></p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.newsitem a{
            color:#1F4F82
            text-decoration:none;
        }

.newsitem a:hover{
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: You have missed a semicolon (`;`) in `.newsitem a` rule sir.

Comment: Note that your selector does not select a *specific* `<a>` element, but instead *every* `<a>` element contained within a `<div class="newsitem">`. Apply the `id=""` attribute to be more specific.

Comment: I change the selector to #content.newsitem a{...}, still not working :( Is the selector correct?

Comment: seems to work fine here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b57wa9r2/), not sure what you're doing wrong

Comment: I added !important then its working. Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

in your first declaration, you're missing a semicolon after setting the color

Answer (score 2):

It is quite working over there. I think there is something you are not doing right either with your code or possibly a conflict.

Likely way to solve this problem
i. Right-Click on the element and click inspect element, then try to edit it using the css selector box on the right side of the your screen
ii. Add `!important` to your code as show below:

```
.newsitem a{
            color:#000000 !important;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

.newsitem a:hover{
            text-decoration:none !important;
        }
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks very much. I added important then its working now. Could you elaborate why I have to use !important there?

Comment: The reason why you have the important attribute is simply because a pre-defined tag might have been set to use some css property. So the important attribute overrides any predefined rules